# How can I make Vim ssd friendlier?

Tags: save

When I append a line to an existing file with Vim,
Vim will unlink that file and create a new one on `:w`,
although that is unnecessary.
Vim even does the same with `~/.viminfo` every time...

I found it out with btrfs-send and btrfs-rec-dump...
example:

```
unlink          ./.homesnap-new/aw/.viminfo
unlink          ./.homesnap-new/aw/bla
mkfile          ./.homesnap-new/o700678-17349-0
rename          ./.homesnap-new/o700678-17349-0 dest=./.homesnap-new/aw/bla
write           ./.homesnap-new/aw/bla          offset=0 len=5
mkfile          ./.homesnap-new/o700679-17349-0
rename          ./.homesnap-new/o700679-17349-0 dest=./.homesnap-new/aw/.viminfo
write           ./.homesnap-new/aw/.viminfo     offset=0 len=36811
```

Comment: Is this actually a problem? I'd really like to know.

Comment: @Friedrich i mentioned it when i looked at the size of my every5minute btrfs snapshots... so at least there it causes a problem... SSDs are quite durable nowadays... i dont know, if one could break them with Vim...

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
:set nowritebackup
```

This feature goes from "the prehistoric era" when disks were small and periodically failed on write.

Also, see `:h backup` for a more complete explanation.

Comment: ok... no unlink anymore... but it still writes the whole file and not just the appended lines... even if the file was unmodified... is it too error prone, to do a append-only write?

Comment: Is there even a single editor that does what you want?

Comment: @romainl r u talking to me? if yes: i like Vim most.. but in fact i'm working on my own little fs, that can write single bytes to a journal (btrfs seems to write full 4KiB blocks)... giggle

Comment: @RRIDDICC AFAIK, no general-purpose text editor tries to treat "append-only" situation as a special one. It just doesn't pay off.

Comment: @Matt ok... thx... same holds true for the "did not change the first half of the file" situation...? is it the job of the fs to catch such things?

Comment: @RRIDDICC Ordinary applications may not know the internals of file system. And therefore they can't (and shouldn't try to) optimize it. FS driver or OS in general, yes, but not apps.

Comment: @Matt ok... i guessed so... but i dont quite understand, why it is considered ok to write the same data over existing data... i tend to even avoid that in main memory, because i feel like the cache manager likes me for that...